# Creating a large number of multiple outputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, distributed

I am creating a large number of output files, for example 500. I am getting already being created exception,as shoen below. The program recovers by itself when the number of output files is small. For ex. if its 50 files, though this exception occurs, the program starts running successfully after printing this exception several times.

But, for many files, it eventually fails with an `IOException`.

I have pasted the error and then the code below:

```
 12/10/29 15:47:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201210231820_0235_r_000004_3, Status : FAILED
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.AlreadyBeingCreatedException: failed to create file /home/users/mlakshm/preopa406/data-r-00004 for DFSClient_attempt_201210231820_0235_r_000004_3 on client 10.0.1.100, because this file is already being created by DFSClient_attempt_201210231820_0235_r_000004_2 on 10.0.1.130
            at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.recoverLeaseInternal(FSNamesystem.java:1406)
```

I have pasted the code :

In the Reduce method, I have the below logic to generate ouputs:

```
                      int data_hash = (int)data_str.hashCode();
                      int data_int1 = 0;
                      int k = 500;
                      int check1 = 0;
                      for (int l = 10; l>0; l++)
                      {

                       if((data_hash%l==0)&&(check1 == 0))
                       {
                       check1 = 1;
                       int range = (int) k/10;

                       String check = "true";


                      while(range > 0 && check.equals("true"))
                                        {

                                     if(data_hash % range-1 == 0)
                                        {                                                        
                                                check = "false";
                                        data_int1 = range*10;

                                     }
                                        }


                            }

                            }

                               mos.getCollector("/home/users/mlakshm/preopa407/cdata"+data_int1, reporter).collect(new Text(t+" "+alsort.get(0)+" "+alsort.get(1)), new Text(intersection));

                        PLs help!
```

Comment: code please for faster answers.

Comment: I ve pasted the part of the code in the reduce class that is causing the exception

Comment: mos is object of Multiple Outputs in hadoop

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all the reducer are trying to write files with the same naming scheme. 
The reason it's doing this because

```
mos.getCollector("/home/users/mlakshm/preopa407/cdata"+data_int1, reporter).collect(new Text(t+" "+alsort.get(0)+" "+alsort.get(1)), new Text(intersection));
```

Set's the file name based on a characteristic of the data not the identity of the reducer.

You have a couple of choices :

1. Rework your map job so so that the key that's emitted matches up with the hash that your calculating in this job. That would make sure that each reducer got a span of values.

   1. Include in the file name a identifier that is unqiue to each mapper. This would leave you with a set of part files for each reducer.

Could you perhaps explain why your using multiple outputs here? I don't think you need to.

Comment: I want the outputs to be in different files, as different reduce classes in the future map reduce jobs will be using different outputs.   But, now if want to include an identifier that is unique to a mapper/reducer, i cannot set that in job conf MultipleOutputs.getNamedOutput(). If I don't set that in job conf, then I ll get undefined named output. :( Any suggestions?

Comment: In my previous comment please note: it is MultipleOutputs.addNamedOutput

Comment: Yeah, the trick here is to create a custom OutputFormat. However, I strongly urge you to consider whether you want to be specifying the file name in your reducer.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. I changed the multiple outputs and now I write directly to the fs, with unique file names.. I don't face the error..